# How to set a checkbox value in code

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have some code like:

```
foreach (var item in Model) {
        <div>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserRole.Role.Name)
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ids" checked="@item.Active" />
        </div>
    }
```

What I was trying to achieve was set the checkbox check if item is Active else not checked.

I understand the syntax should be `checked="checked"` and I've set it up as `checked="true"`

I don't understand how to convert the true to checked and what to do for false.

I was trying to use a ternary but it wouldn't play nice. Can anybody help?

Comment: Whatever server-side language/framework you're using - please tag the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of the checked attribute will cause it to be checked, i.e It doesn't matter (AFAIK) what the value of the attribute is. So you need to detect whether or not to add the checked attribute at all:

```
foreach (var item in Model) 
{
        <div>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserRole.Role.Name)
        </div>
        <div>
               <input type="checkbox" name="ids" @if (item.Active) { Write("checked"); }/>
        </div>
    }
```

Edited: changed to  MДΓΓ БДLL version, much cleaner.

One brute force approach =P

Comment: I'm not that familiar with this particular flavor of templating. Wouldn't this work just as well, and be more DRY? `<input type="checkbox" name="ids" if (item.Active) { checked="checked" }/>`

Comment: Never seen it done that way before. I'll edit my answer. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Worked the way you orinally had it. The new way the are all checked regardless of the input. An example of the generated markup <input type="checkbox" }="" checked="checked" {="" (item.active)="" if="" name="ids">

Comment: @ MДΓΓ БДLL Had to add a little more in order to be valid. Requires the @ to detect that you are C# code and then you need to call Write() to print out the html you want.

Comment: @AnonyMouse I just made corrections after testing it. I took  MДΓΓ БДLL, comment as fact without checking into it, DOH (not a mark against him either)!

Answer (score 1):

> I understand the syntax should be `checked="checked"`

If you are using XHTML, that is true. In HTML the shorthand syntax [is recommended](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.4) where you specify only the value of that attribute (although user agents don't have a problem with the long for these days, it is quicker to type).

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar" checked>
```

> I don't understand how to convert the true to checked

That depends on the (unspecified) template language you are using.

> and what to do for false.

Don't include the checked attribute at all.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar">
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, to uncheck it, just remove the checked="whatever" attribute.  Technically, HTML doesn't care what the value of checked="" is, just that it exists and that it's valid markup.

Comment: Not really. `checked` is a boolean property. Valid values are `true` or `false`. Everything else is invalid.

Comment: @dotweb, that is incorrect, as ozbarry said any value is allowed for it to evaluate to true.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Looks like we are both wrong. I just tried it out with the (HTML5) validator and only the value `checked` seems to be allowed.

Comment: @dotweb, that would be to case in xhtml but not html.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I said I tried with HTML5. ;) I would undo the down vote but it looks like I'm not able to anymore.

Comment: HTML has always cared what the value is. HTML 5 accepts either `checked` or an empty string. Everything else accepts only `checked`. In HTML 5 you can specify just the attribute name. In HTML 4 and earlier you can specify just the value. In XHTML you must specify both.